# What on-topic works have “data” in their title?

Tags: discussion, tags, winterbash

A friend of mine wants to get the “You Got Splunk!” hat from Winter Bash 2022 on Sci Fi & Fantasy SE.  This requires that they ask or answer a question with “data” in the name of a tag.  What on topic works should they read or watch in the three weeks to make this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This query](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=data&C=AND&USE_2=title_language_free&O_2=exact&TERM_2=english&USE_3=title_ttype&O_3=exact&TERM_3=NOVEL&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title) finds 6 novels with "data" in the title, including *The Terra Data* by Tubb.

| Publication Date | Title | Author |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1908-00-00 | *Geyserland: Empricisms in Social Reform. Being Data and Observations recorded by the late Mark Stubble, M.D., Ph.D.* | Richard Hatfield |
| 1967-00-00 | *The Golden Boats of Taradata Affair* | E. C. Eliott |
| 1971-08-00 | *Data for Death* | Johannes Allen |
| 1980-04-00 | *The Terra Data* | E. C. Tubb |
| 2006-10-00 | *A Fistful of Data* | Stephen Dedman |
| 2020-10-21 | *The Data Riot* | D. L. Young |

[The second query](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=data&C=AND&USE_2=title_language_free&O_2=exact&TERM_2=english&USE_3=title_ttype&O_3=exact&TERM_3=SHORTFICTION&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title) finds dozens of shorter works including "Preliminary Data" by Moorcock and "Datableed" by Cadigan.

| Publication Date | Title | Author |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1824-00-00 | Maredata | N. G. |
| 1952-03-00 | Incomplete Data | H. B. Fyfe |
| 1952-09-00 | Zero Data | Charles Saphro |
| 1953-09-00 | The Available Data on the Worp Reaction | Lion Miller |
| 1959-09-00 | On Handling the Data | M. I. Mayfield |
| 1965-07-00 | In the Light of Further Data | Christopher Anvil |
| 1965-08-00 | Preliminary Data | Michael Moorcock |
| 1971-00-00 | Second Run at the Data | Douglas R. Mason |
| 1972-00-00 | Maredata and Giulio, or The Ocean Spirit | Anonymous |
| 1981-00-00 | Dialect of the Data Disk | Celeste Newbrough |
| 1984-11-00 | According to Scientific Data | Vladen Bakhnov |
| 1989-04-00 | Mission Report: 'Datalore' | Robert Greenberger |
| 1989-04-00 | Mission Report: 'Elementary, Dear Data' | Patrick Daniel O'Neill |
| 1990-10-00 | Data-Link | Kay Fortunato |
| 1991-06-00 | Mission Report: 'Data's Day' | Patrick Daniel O'Neill |
| 1992-04-00 | Preliminary Data | F. Alexander Brejcha |
| 1993-08-00 | Mission Report: 'A Fistful of Datas' | John Sayers |
| 1994-02-00 | The Data Class | Ben Jeapes |
| 1998-00-00 | A Clockwork Data: Not by Anthony Burgess Steven R. Boyett |  |
| 1998-00-00 | Less Than Data: Not by Bret Easton Ellis | Steven R. Boyett |
| 1998-03-00 | Datableed | Pat Cadigan |
| 1998-07-00 | What Went Through Data's Mind 0.68 Seconds Before the Satellite Hit | Dylan Otto Krider |
| 2000-00-00 | Kamikaze Motives of the Immaculate Deconstruction in the Data-Sucking Rust-Age of Insectile Hackers | Lance Olsen |
| 2001-04-00 | Kandata in Hell's Eye | Daniel E. Blackston |
| 2002-05-00 | Starfleet Technical Database: Intrepid Class Design Lineage | Rick Sternbach |
| 2002-11-00 | Starfleet Technical Database: Klingon Personal Weapons | Rick Sternbach |
| 2003-00-00 | Biographical Data (The Thackery T. Lambshead Pocket Guide to Eccentric & Discredited Diseases) | uncredited |
| 2003-01-00 | Starfleet Technical Database: U.S.S. Stargazer | Rick Sternbach |
| 2003-02-00 | Starfleet Technical Database: Romulan Propulsion | Rick Sternbach |
| 2003-04-00 | Starfleet Technical Database: Aeroshuttle Technology | Rick Sternbach |
| 2003-06-00 | Protecting Data's Friends | Scott William Carter |
| 2005-11-14 | Through the Data Storm | David Lawrence |
| 2006-04-00 | Datacide | Steve Bein |
| 2010-04-00 | Data Crabs | Deborah Walker |
| 2012-06-12 | The Art of Data Tri-So | Vincent Morgan |
| 2012-08-05 | Datafall | Rich Larson |
| 2012-08-14 | Top Secret - Swipe data recovered - Group A - Subject: Teresa | James Dashner |
| 2013-01-24 | Corrupted Data Found on a Fire Damaged Hard Drive | Anonymous |
| 2013-07-00 | The Data Runners Above Our Heads: A Documentary | Stephen Gaskell |
| 2013-10-11 | Data Dogs | Eric V. Hardenbrook |
| 2013-12-08 | Data Suck | Benjamin Kane Ethridge |
| 2014-04-07 | Data Dump | Trisha L. Senbastian |
| 2014-07-22 | A Perfectly Stable Dataglobule | K. J. Russell |
| 2014-08-00 | Undermarket Data | An Owomoyela |
| 2014-09-00 | Patterns of a Murmuration, in Billions of Data Points | JY Yang |
| 2014-09-10 | Data Feed | Natsuya Uesugi |
| 2014-11-17 | Targeted Strike 2: Judgement Database | Adam Rothstein |
| 2015-06-00 | Her Data Like Fingerprints | Ashley M. Hill |
| 2015-06-02 | The Data Tourist | Davien Thomas |
| 2016-01-28 | The End of Big Data | James Bridle |
| 2016-06-01 | Star Kitty: The Data Files | Faith Blum |
| 2017-04-00 | The Frost Giant's Data | Dan Abnett |
| 2017-07-00 | The Law of Conservation of Data | John Grant |
| 2017-08-00 | The Headspace Database | Helen French |
| 2017-10-03 | The Sith of Datawork | Ken Liu |
| 2017-10-08 | The dataSultan of Streets and Stars | Jeremy Szal |
| 2017-10-19 | Patient Data | Claire Buss |
| 2017-12-11 | The Data Eaters | Anna O'Brien |
| 2018-03-15 | Data | João Ramalho-Santos |
| 2018-03-20 | Data Transfer | Nick Morrison |
| 2018-03-23 | Data Stream | Claire Buss |
| 2018-06-19 | Data Recovery | Nicholas Jennings |
| 2019-01-13 | Tasting the Data Flow | Marcie Franks |
| 2019-03-05 | Three Data Units | Kitty-Lydia Dye |
| 2019-07-00 | Captain Zack & the Data Raiders | Steve Rasnic Tem |
| 2019-07-07 | The Risks and Advantages of Data Migration | Kim Fielding |
| 2019-07-28 | A Pebble in the Data Stream | Michelle F. Goddard |
| 2019-10-00 | Data | Laurence Barratt-Manning |
| 2020-10-28 | Don't Worry About Your Data | Sita Narayan-Dinanauth |
| 2021-02-28 | Unlimited Data | Eugen Bacon |
| 2021-05-00 | Dendrochromatic Data Recovery Report 45-27 | Steve Toase |
| 2021-07-12 | Data Migration | Melanie Harding-Shaw |
| 2022-02-26 | Data, Not Data | J. Charles Ramirez |
| 2022-06-07 | Uncovered Data | David Drake |
| 2022-07-00 | Sorceress Datale's Apprentice | B. T. Petro |

Comment: And one hit for the singular form: ["The Quagma Datum"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?82326) by Stephen Baxter.

Comment: Good job. But https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11115 *Android at Arms* is in ISFDB, so your query is incomplete.

Comment: @b_jonas I wouldn't imagine that "\*d-at-a\*" matches a pattern of "data", so I don't think that is useful.

Comment: Besides, you'd have to search individually for "d at a" (9 English matches), "d a ta" (9 English matches), "da ta" (3 English matches, 7 other), "dat a" (5 matches, none English), and "d ata" (3 English matches) and adding punctuation makes it worse:  "d: a ta" has 36 matches.

Comment: @DavidW I believe Stack Exchange considers tags equivalent if they differ only in hyphens, eg. if you try to tag your question with [mar-vel] it will get the [tag:marvel] tag. Because of that I'm hoping the hat matches regardless of hyphens in the tag name too, and if it turns out that it doesn't, that's a bug that I'll loudly complain about on the main meta.

Comment: Why overthink this so much?  Just ask a question about Data from *Star Trek*.

Answer (score 6):

- ***Android at Arms*** (1971), book by Andre Norton
- ***Cold Hearted: A Tale of the Wicked Stepmother*** (2021), book by Serena Valentino based on Disney's *Cinderella*
- *Star Trek: the New Generation* TV series, or the movies in that sub-franchise, because the character **Data** has his own tag [star-trek-data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-data)

Alternately, if your friend is technical-minded, they may post on the site Meta about [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) or the [data-dumps](/questions/tagged/data-dumps).

Comment: Does that mean that SE's system strips hyphens from the tag in assessing eligibility? Naughty, naughty. They'll be getting coal in their stockings.